# Rails autoloading fully capitalized name like API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, constants

I have some structure

- /lib/dokuwiki.rb
- /lib/dokuwiki/exception.rb
- /lib/dokuwiki/api/connection.rb

**dokuwiki.rb**

```
require 'dokuwiki/exception.rb'

module Dokuwiki
  ...
```

**dokuwiki/api/connection.rb**

```
module Dokuwiki
  module API
    class Connection
      ...
```

Now, when I try to call `Dokuwiki::API::Connection.new` from a controller (without any `require`), Rails default constants autoloading fails. I believe this is because the `::API` module should have a folder named `/a_p_i/` instead of `/api/` but that's ugly.

Of course I could require 'dokuwiki/api/connection.rb', in the main '/lib/dokuwiki.rb' file, but then it wouldn't reload this class automatically (which is kinda annoying in a dev context)

What can I do to keep the nice `/api/` folder name and be able to do some live modifications to `/lib/dokuwiki/api/connection.rb` without having to restart my server ?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

There's a file called `config/initializers/inflections.rb`.

Add in it

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'API' 
end
```

and the API namespace will be available as a directory called `api`

Comment: Love this.  I added inflect.acronym 'SMS' and all my things that deal with SMS in my app work as expected.  Is this a bad thing/unconventional thing?